# How to get ASMX generated WSDL soap:address to use https

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl, asmx

The WSDL definitions in Production and Community Testing include a reference to “HTTP” instead of “HTTPS”.  The definitions in the two test environments are correct using “HTTPS”.

A client discovered this problem when developing their SOAP over HTTPS connection to the web service.  For whatever reason they read in the WSDL each time they do a PushList (method of web service).

WRONG:

soap:address location="http://www.xxxxxxx.net/xxxxxxxxxx/webservices/PIR/Service.asmx"

RIGHT:

soap:address location="https://www.xxxxxxx.net/xxxxxxxxxx/webservices/PIR/Service.asmx"

How can I correct this?  I've seen stuff about overriding reflection ande what not, but why would some environments be correct while others are wrong? I'm hoping for an easier solution...

Answer (score 0):

What we discovered, was that it depends on how we accessed the service, if we accessed the service using HTTP in the URL, then the location would have http, if HTTPS, then the location would be HTTPS.